# How to prove $\lim_{a\to 0} \left( a\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(na)\right) = \int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity

> Let $f:[0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that :
>
> - $\forall x<y:f(x)\ge f(y)$
> - $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x) \ dx <\infty $
> - $f\in C[0,\infty )$
>
> Prove:
>
> 1. $\forall a>0 : \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(na)<\infty $
> 2. $\lim_{a\to 0} \left( a\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(na)\right) = \int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)\, dx$

---

Sol for $(1)$:

In short:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{(n-1)a}^{na}f(x)dx\geq a\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(na)$$

For more details: [Given a decreasing function s.t. $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx<\infty,$ prove $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(na)$ converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2402659/given-a-decreasing-function-s-t-int-0-infty-fx-dx-infty-prove-sum-n)

---

EDIT:
For $2$ I tried to make this look like Riemann sum but I didn't know how to start.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What definition of integral are you working with? If $a = 1/N$ for some big integer N, then this is a standard Riemann sum (but the integral is improper). You can control the other possible values of $a$ by arguing they're sandwiched between such values.

Comment: @hunter I tried using Riemann sum (I'm gonna add it to my post). I'm looking for the algebraic manipulations that gives you somthing similar to Riemann sum.

Comment: This is related to direct Riemann integrability, which is used in Renewal theory.  See Proposition 4.1 in Asmussen, S. Applied Probability and Queues, Springer,  pp. 154-155

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution to (1) is very nearly a solution to (2).  Just note in addition that $$\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx \leq a\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(na)$$ and $\lim_{a\to 0^+} af(0)=0$.

In particular, this implies $$\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx - af(0) \leq a \sum_{n=1}^\infty f(na) \leq \int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx$$
and the sandwich theorem allows us to conclude.

Comment: I notice that, but it implies that $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) dx =0$

Comment: @Lior How could it possibly imply that?  I've added more details.

Comment: Ohh, I missed it. Thanks!